# Can't add font when converting from html to pdf with iText Library.Using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, itext, html-to-pdf

> i am using itext library for convert html to pdf. i can convert properly, but can't add the font.My converter code is here

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS);
cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper(Configuration.DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS));
Template t = new Template("templateName", new StringReader(templateHTML), cfg);
Writer out = new FileWriter(new File(TARGET + documentName + ".html"));
t.process(model, out);
out.close();

ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.setBaseUri(TARGET);
File output = new File(TARGET + documentName + ".pdf");

FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider();
FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(FONT);
fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(
    new FileInputStream(TARGET + documentName + ".html"),
    new FileOutputStream(TARGET + documentName + ".pdf"),
    properties);
```

> My Target and Font is here

```
  public static String TARGET = "target/classes/documentsTemplate/";
  public static final String FONT = "./src/main/resources/fonts/special.ttf";
```

> I also tried adding font to html like this

```
* {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: local("C:/font/special.ttf");
}

.text-font {
    font-family: "myFirstFont";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved with this code .

```
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
fontProvider.addFont(FONT);
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
```

but I couldn't make my font bold

Answer (score 0):

Using the following gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itext7-core', version: '7.2.5'
    implementation group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'html2pdf', version: '5.0.0'
    implementation group: 'ognl', name: 'ognl', version: '3.1.12'
```

I am attaching the solution that worked for me:

```
    // file is inside resources at the path specified here
    public static final String FONT = "templates/fonts/Sans-Serif-Medium.ttf";

    // font set up
    FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
    FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(FONT);
    fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
    converterProperties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
```

Bold does not work unfortunately.

**EDIT**

In order for bold to work, you need to add the bold font. So the code working for bold is the following:

```
    public static final String FONT = "templates/fonts/arial.ttf";
    public static final String FONT_BOLD = "templates/fonts/arial-bold.ttf";

    // font set up
    FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
    FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(FONT);
    FontProgram fontProgramBold = FontProgramFactory.createFont(FONT_BOLD);
    fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
    ontProvider.addFont(fontProgramBold);
    converterProperties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
```